# Google sheets "series selector" color doesn't match line color

Tags: google-sheets

How do I force the google sheets "series selector" color (in settings for series) to match the color assigned to the lines for the series?

[image]

In my sheet, when I change the line color, the selector color doesn't change to match it.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot change the Series colour assignment - it is created by Google Sheets at the time of creating the chart.

In any event, while you mention the **Line** colour you didn't mention that the **Fill** colour can also be varied, as can the **Opacity** of both those colours. So, it is never a simple matter of substituting one colour for another.

Comment: So the series selector color, though clearly intended to match the color used for the series in the chart, only does so if you don’t modify the color in the chart after creation?

Comment: Look at it another way, that colour is part of the build of the chart, you can modify the line and fill colours and their opacity as much and as often as you wish, but you retain the continuity of the original colour. I think your reflection might be a somewhat cynical (though, I myself am a most cynical person too). It might be simply better to say “it is what it is”.